# Expanding queue overwrites all previous entries with new entry

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, queue, overwrite

I have written a queuing program that allows the user to enter student objects into a queue. Here is my section of the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
private void resize(int max) {
    assert max >= numOfNodes;
    StudentListing[] temp = (StudentListing[]) new Object[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNodes; i++) {
        temp[i] = data[(front + i) % data.length];
    }
    data = temp;
    front = 0;
    rear = numOfNodes;
}

public void enqueue(StudentListing newNode) {
    if (numOfNodes == data.length) {
        resize(data.length * 2);
    }
    data[rear++] = newNode;
    if (rear == data.length) {
        rear = 0;
    }
    numOfNodes++;
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I go to add a new student into the queue and it is full, it carries out the resize method and overwrites all of my previous entries with the new student entry.

For example: a student named John gets added to the queue with a maximum size of 1. The user goes to add another student named Tom to the queue; it expands the queue, but then overwrites John. The end result is that there are two Toms in the queue instead of one John and one Tom.

I need help figuring out how to stop it from overwriting and instead add all previous entries to the newly created expanded queue, and then add the new entry to the end of said queue. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Whoa! That's a lot of code.  We all like to help out but you should condense your problem down to something manageable for both you and us.

Comment: Just did it, sorry about that